# Create a list out of a comparison between two lists C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Suppose I have two lists of type `MyCustomType`, a class which could be like this:

```
public class MyCustomType{
    public int Classification {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

I want to create a third list of type `Tuple<MyCustomType,MyCustomType>`, which will contain some sort of a "full outer join" between them, based on a condition (e.g. put them together if they got the same Title and Classification)

Example:

```
list1:
Classification      Title      Text
Movie               300        bla
Game                Star Wars  the dark side are they

list2:
Movie               300        updated bla
TV Show             CSI        cool
```

The result then would be

```
list3: 
MyCustomType                                             MyCustomType
Movie               300        bla                       Movie               300        updated bla
Game                Star Wars  the dark side are they    (null)
(null)                                                   TV Show             CSI        cool
```

They would match items by Classification and Title, and put a null on the other side when one does not match.

How could I do that (possibly using LINQ?)

I'm developing in C#, .NET 4.0.

I want this for my experimental project for C#, a 'semantic' C# merge tool using Roslyn. I want to compare and match SyntaxNodes by type and name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outer joins are not natively supported in Linq. But you can do a left join and a right join, and then put the two together:

```
var left = 
    from x in list1
    join y in list2
        on new { x.Title, x.Classification }
        equals { y.Title, y.Classification }
        into tmp
    from y in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select Tuple.Create(x, y);

var right = 
    from y in list2
    join x in list1
        on new { y.Title, y.Classification }
        equals { x.Title, x.Classification }
        into tmp
    from y in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where x == null // already included in left
    select Tuple.Create(x, y);

var result = left.Concat(right);
```

---

EDIT: if you want an outer non-equijoin, you can do something like that:

```
var left = 
    from x in list1
    from y in list2.Where(y2 => MatchSyntaxNode(x, y2)).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select Tuple.Create(x, y);

var right = 
    from y in list2
    from x in list1.Where(x2 => MatchSyntaxNode(x2, y)).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where x == null // already included in left
    select Tuple.Create(x, y);

var result = left.Concat(right);
```

(untested)

Comment: Is there any way I could use the join with a predicate ? so I could write something like `join y in list2 on MatchSyntaxNode(x,y)` ?

Comment: In the second declaration (var right), instead of `join` I should put `from`, right? And thanks, it worked. I'm marking as answer.

Comment: @ConradClark, yes, it was just a typo. I fixed it

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
firstList.Select(x=>new Tuple<YourType,YourType>(x, secondList.FirstOrDefault(__yourcondition__)))
        .Union(secondList.Any(!firstList.Any(__yourcondition__))
        .Select(x=>new Tuple<YourType,YourType>(null, x));
```

A "left join", concatenated with a right join.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly as well, I'm +1ing it since I can only mark one answer.